# AKS resource quota issue - not allowing to create pod

Tags: kubernetes

We have created resource quota object in AKS using following Yaml details  -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: {Namespacename}
spec:
  hard:
    requests.cpu: "1"
    requests.memory: 2Gi
    limits.cpu: "2"
    limits.memory: 4Gi
```

and respective changes are applied at container level for request and limit (Memory and CP). After applying this changes, pods are not getting created. Even it doesn't show any error.

Need guidance/help on this if anyone face this issue already.

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean to say that, pod creation was successful without attaching resourceQuota ?

Comment: If you are using a Deployment object, check the events of the ReplicaSets that it creates, you will find the reason for the pod creation issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Namespace request/limits are the settings that affect **every pod/container in a given namespace** as a whole.

What this means is **if you do not set your pod request/limits correctly you may not be able to deploy your pod to that quota enabled namespace regardless of the nodes available resources.**

Instead of throttling, you simply won’t be allowed to deploy if the quota would be breached.

When you have namespace quota’s setup in order to deploy to that namespace your pod has to have request/limits defined or the pod will not be scheduled for deployment.

Please check [AKS Performance: Resource Quotas](https://itnext.io/aks-performance-resource-quotas-2934ce468be7) for fuull explanation with work examples.